# increase /dev/sda1 size which is mounted to / (root)

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, resize

I have ubuntu running on VMWare & its live production server running since 2 years. 
dev/sda1 is primary partition and mounted on /.

I have increased hdd size 500 to 1TB yesterday. 
fdisk -l shows 1 TB size.

But it won't apply in dev/sda1 automatic.

does resiez2fs command increase dev/sda1 size?

Or any other command require to run?

Please help me on this.

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitions don't automatically resize themselves to fill the entire capacity of the drive.

1. Download [the Ubuntu Live CD](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and boot into it.
2. Install GParted and open it.
3. Open the drop-down menu at the top and select your hard drive.
4. Move everything except for /dev/sda1 to the right of the bar.
5. Right click on /dev/sda1 and click resize. Set free space preceding (MiB) to 0, Set New Size as high as you can, and set Free space following (MiB) to 0.

[image: Resize Dialog]

6. Click Resize
7. Click the apply check mark.

[image: Main Window]

Answer (score 0):

Use the GParted application to resize your partitions. You can open the application, right click the partition that is mounted on `/` and resize it to fill your disk space.